# running javascript in head, cant use window.onload, can't use jquery

Tags: javascript, html

I've got the following code that get's a URL parameter, selects an option from a select element and then hides the div the select is in.

It's going to be on a form that supplied by a 3rd party service, I only have access to a js file in the head of the form, there's lots of other javascript. **jQuery can't be used** (it's not in the head).

What I'm unsure of is how to run the code after the rest of the page has loaded (or at least the elements needed), I can't use window.onload, and I want to wrap things up as much as possible to avoid any chance of variables with same names elsewhere.

Thanks.

```
function getURLparameter( variable ){
variable = variable.replace(/[\[]/,"\\\[").replace(/[\]]/,"\\\]");
var regexS = "[\\?&]"+variable+"=([^&#]*)";
var regex = new RegExp( regexS );
var results = regex.exec( window.location.href );
if( results == null )
    return "";
else
    return results[1];
}
var typeNum = {
    abc: {
        redirectURL: 'http://www.1.com',
        optionIndex: 1
    }, 
    123: {
        redirectURL: 'http://www.2.com',
        optionIndex: 2
    },
    //etc etc
};

var formId = getURLparameter('SurveyID');


if (formId === 384) {
    var urlType = getURLparameter('type');
    var theType = typeNum[urlType];
    var selectDiv = ('the_div');
    var selectField = ('the_select');
    if (urlType in typeNum) {
        document.getElementById(selectField).options[theType.optionIndex].selected = true;
        document.getElementById(selectDiv).style.visibility = "hidden";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<strike>You need to put it at the bottom of the page below all the elements you are accessing in the script.</strike>

If you want to wrap it then use [self-executing anonymous function](http://markdalgleish.com/2011/03/self-executing-anonymous-functions/):

```
(function() {
  // all your code should be moved here
})();
```

This way no variables and functions defined inside will be accessible outside.

#### Update (see comments):

If `window.onload` is used by another script you can still add your own code there:

```
// previous onload function - defined in another script for example
window.onload = function() {
  document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = "hello";
};

// we will add another function to onload
window.onload = (function() {
  // previous onload function
  var oldonload = window.onload;

  // return new onload function ...
  return function() {
    // .. that will call previous onload
    oldonload();
    // and add something extra
    document.getElementById("test").innerHTML += " world!";
  };
})();
```

**[HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/dzejkej/avBvx/)** is the code.

#### EDIT:

A comment by *symcbean*:

> Or rather than using a closure, just use window.addEventListener() http://developer.mozilla.org/en/Code_snippets/On_page_load

For IE versions < 9 `attachEvent()` must be used. See [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.addEventListener).

Comment: that's part of the picture, thanks. I only have access to one js file in the html `<head>`.

Comment: @acowley So you can only modify that one JS in the `<head>` but no HTML? Why can't you use `window.onload`?

Comment: there's another js file in the head that uses it. That's potentially a problem right?

Comment: Or rather than using a closure, just use window.addListener() https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Code_snippets/On_page_load

Comment: Very comprehensive thank you. Most of this well past what I know right now (obviously :p) but it does work. Thanks again

Comment: @acowley See my answer for a sorter and more portable approach.

Answer (score 2):

```
// wrap it all in an anonymous function
(function (callback) {
  if (document.readyState === "complete") {
    // if the document already has finished loading, execute immediately
    callback();
  } else {
    // if it hasn't finished yet, attach the callback to the load event
    if ( document.addEventListener ) {  /* Opera, Firefox, Webkit */
      window.addEventListener("load", callback, false);
    } else if ( document.attachEvent ) {  /* IE */
      window.attachEvent("onload", callback);
    }
  }
})(
  // immediately call that anonymous function, passing your callback 
  function () { 
    // this will be executed when the DOM is ready, 
    // so put all your stuff here
  }
);
```

Comment: @acowley That's easily fixed. :) - I should have voted on the question  anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Set up an interval every 100ms to check whether your element is ready or not...

```
(function() {
    var myInterval = setInterval( function () {
        if( var myElement = document.getElementById('idOfYourElement') ) {
            clearInterval( myInterval );
            // do what you want to do with myElement.
        }
    }, 100 );
})();
```

Comment: You forgot to use `var` keywords for your variable declarations.

Comment: Yes and I should have wrapped it inside an anon function to prevent leakage to global scope, corrected.

Comment: You still forgot to use `var` keyword